# Why does my counting sort algorithm not sort at all?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void SortCount(vector<int>& vec){
    int max_el = *max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    vector<int> C(max_el+1, 0);
    vector<int> B(vec.size(), 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        C[vec[i]] = C[vec[i]] + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= vec.size(); i++){
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ ) {
        B[C[vec[i]] - 1] = vec[i];
        C[vec[i]] = C[vec[i]] - 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        vec[i] = B[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<int> vec {5,2,43,31,67,311};
    SortCount(vec);

    for (size_t i=0;  i <vec.size();  i++) {
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I did exactly by the book but for some reason it just prints out the values in the same orders they were placed in. Where did I mess up?

Edit: I added the main function

Comment: You find `max_el`, but never use it anywhere.  Perhaps this is a problem?

Comment: I don't see *anywhere* in your code where you actually change (or even assign anything to) any element of the given `vec` argument! You're just changing (maybe) things in local copies.

Comment: I edited the code, accidentally used the experimental thing I tried. I use the max_el.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that? How can I fix that?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Please try to post *the exact code* you are asking questions about. Cut and paste it from your code editor. It's hard to give meaningful help otherwise.

Comment: Done. Mind is hazy because this has been bothering me for hours

Comment: I would love to but my assignment is to write a counting sort, so no cutting corners there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766

Comment: I highly doubt using namespace std; is not making my count sort work.

Comment: It's not, which is why it's not an answer, but a comment. You appear to be learning C++, so the link might be valuable to you.

Comment: The point of someone posting that link is to try to urge you to break this bad practice now before it hurts you in the future. No it's not causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your iteration over the count array has the wrong bounds:

```
//for(int i = 1; i <= vec.size(); i++) { <--wrong
for(int i = 1; i < C.size(); i++) {
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
}
```

---

Also you should get in the habit of using `std::size_t` as a type for an index instead of `int`. `int` is both too small and also is signed, so it is unsuited for indices.